# Como adicionar 13,10 depois de ler linha de caracteres ?

Tags: assembly

Estou a tentar gravar uma matriz de caracteres 40x20, fazendo 2 ciclos, em que lê caráter a caráter guarda em um buffer, mas eu sei que temos que adicionar 13,10 para mudar de linha e o cursor voltar para o inicio. Mas o 13,10 é considerado um byte? Como posso adicionar o 13,10 no final da linha ou seja depois de chegar ao ultimo caráter da linha.

*Parte do código*

```
xor cx,cx
xor si,si
xor ax,ax

mov cx, 20
forLine: 
    forColumn:
        mov         ah, 08h ; Guarda o Caracter que est� na posi��o do Cursor
        mov     bh,0        ; numero da p�gina
        int     10h 
        mov caraterLido, ah     
        mov buffer[SI], caraterLido
        inc si
        cmp si, 40
        jne forColumn
        //quando for igual a 40, adicionar 13 e 10 no fim da linha 

loop forLine
```

Comment: Não seria: mov buffer[SI], $A inc si mov buffer[SI], $D ?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo porque o $A e $D?

Comment: Eu quis dizer 10 e 13 em Hexa, mas isso é em Delphi. Agora acho que em assembly o correto seria: 

mov buffer[SI], 0AH inc si mov buffer[SI], 0DH